# Why do literal arrays work, but not coded arrays?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.js. If I pass the chart creator the example code:

```
var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
```

It works fine. However, when I try and pass it this object:

```
function ChartDataObject(labels, datasets)
{
    this.labels = Array();
    this.datasets = Array();
    this.datasets = datasets;
    this.labels = labels;
}
```

Where `labels` and `datasets` are arrays and arrays of arrays, respectively. Both `labels` and `datasets` both show:

```
[object Element], [object Element], etc
```

When I alert them as follows:

```
alert(labels);
alert(datasets);
```

I know that they are filled with string values, and the number of elements in them is correct. Is there something that I am missing in order for Chart.js to see them the same way it sees the `data` object? I should note, that the Chart.js does generate, however the labels all read `[object Element]` and the data does not show (Because it thinks that it is `[object Element]` instead of a number I think).

How do I convert the coded arrays to work the same as the literal created arrays?

EDIT:

`dataset` Object:

```
function Dataset(webrequest, fillColor, strokeColor)
{
    this.webrequest = webrequest;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
    this.data = Array();
}
```

`dataset.data` filling:

```
var valuesArray = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("value");
for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++)
{
    that.datasets[a].data[i] = valuesArray[i];
}
```

Comment: datasets is not an array of arrays. It is an array of objects

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` on your `ChartDataObject` and compare the result with the above literal.

Comment: @thg435 That gives the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: @musefan So how do I change that? I'm not very familiar with Arrays of Arrays

Comment: Can you post your code to fiddle or gist.github.com so we can see what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely that whatever you are passing to your constructor for `labels` and `data` is not in the correct form.  For us to help identify exactly what your issue is, you will have to show us the code you are using to create those data structures.

If you do it like this, it will reproduce what was in the sample code:

```
// array of names
var names = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"];

// array of objects
var items = [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ];


function ChartDataObject(labels, datasets)
{
    this.datasets = datasets;
    this.labels = labels;
}

var obj = new ChartDataObject(names, items);
// now obj should be in the same form as the data variable in the sample code
```

Comment: @jfriend000 I would love to be able to pass the data like this, however the number of arrays in items and the number of elements in names are variable.

Comment: @Asryael - So, create your `names` and `items` variables dynamically.  If you create them in the correct form, there should be no problem.  We can't help you further unless you show us the code that is creating those.